# Can two conjunctions (but and because) be used together?

Tags: conjunctions

I confused with this sentence:

> The Emplyee class is a superclass, but not because it is superior to its subclass

I know both "but" and "because" can be conj. for connecting two sentences. But here the sentence use both of them to connect two sentences. My question is this situation can be allowed? and why? and also there is a "not" between the "but" and "because" to represent a negative meaning, so if I want to negate a conj., just directly add a "not" in front of it? can anyone tell me more about how to use "not" here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can put two conjunctions together, but only if the first one is a coordinating conjunction (*and, or, so, but, for, yet, nor*) and the second one a subordinating conjunction (*because, after, although, since*, etc.).

For example, *but because* and *so although* are correct, but not *because but* or *although so*.

As for the position of *not*, it comes before the subordinating conjunction it modifies. Consequently, your sentence is grammatical as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not use both of them to connect the two sentences. The structure is a little complicated, but it means something like

> The Employee class is a superclass, but this is not because it is superior to its subclass

so structurally, *but* and *because* introduce two different clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is an example.

> She is done, and because of that she gets to watch TV.